# How to have multiple input sources to a hosted console app in C#?

Tags: c#, console-application, read-eval-print-loop, inter-process-communicat

I'd like to build a interactive script app that lets the user write single expressions in a REPL but also lets them send code to it from a code editor. I thought I'd try a solution where the REPL is a console app and the editor a separate application that hosts the console app. So the console app (REPL) must accept both user input from the keyboard but also from the editor application.

If I host the console app (REPL) in the editor I can redirect standard input which makes it possible to send text (code) to the console app (see code below). But is it possible to somehow have multiple input sources to the console app or to switch input sources during run time so that the user can both type code in the REPL and send code to it from the code editor? Or must I have a single process solution?

```
Process replProc = new Process();
replProc.StartInfo.FileName = "repl.exe";
replProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
replProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
replProc.Start();
StreamWriter replWriter = replProc.StandardInput;
replWriter.WriteLine(@"
    public class ScriptedClass 
    {
       public string HelloRepl
       {
          get { return ""Hello from editor!"";}
       }
    }");
```

Comment: You might use [WCF](https://gorillacoding.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/using-wcf-for-inter-process-communication/) for inter-process-communication...

Comment: .. or [pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)